# sendkeys removes last two characters when using appium

Tags: appium

When i enter username using sendkeys in text box as "JOHN" it enters correctly but then removes the last two characters and before going to next textbox it enters only "JO" i have written code in java and using appium.

Comment: can you share the code, error if any received, to answer your question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It could help if you add clicking into the next field before the input itself.